How to configure Cypress component tests with dotenv
I can't make Cypress component tests work with dotenv.
This setup works with the actual application and in Cypres e2e tests, but wen I try to run any component test (even if the component is not using dotenv) I get such error:
ERROR in path/to/some.component.ts:12:23 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'process'. 
Do you need to install type definitions for node? 
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and then add 'node' to the types field in your tsconfig

some.component.ts tests will fail but, all tests of components that do not use process.env.* are passing despite the error.
I have @types/node in my package.json, and my tsconfig.json looks like this:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"],
}

I also have separate tsconfig.json inside cypress directory as suggested in the documentation (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfigjson), but this config seems to affect only e2e tests - if I break this file e.g. with some invalid characters only e2e tests fail to start.
Application is created with angular-cli and uses @angular-builders/custom-webpack
